# Calculating the average of specific numbers in a mixed text file?

Tags: python, python-3.x, average

I have a program that reads a file that has student **names**, **IDs**, **majors**, and **GPAs** in it.

For example (there is much more to the file):

```
OLIVER
8117411
English
2.09
OLIVIA
6478288
Law
3.11
HARRY
5520946
English
1.88
AMELIA
2440501
French
2.93
```

I have to figure out:

- which medicine majors made the honor roll and
- **the average GPA of all the math majors**

All I have right now is the list of medicine majors that made honor roll. I have no idea how to start calculating the average GPA of math majors. Any help is appreciated, and thanks in advance.

This is the code I currently have:

```
import students6

file = open("students.txt")

name = "x"
while name != "":
    name, studentID, major, gpa = students6.readStudents6(file)
    print(name, gpa, major, studentID)

    if major == "Medicine" and gpa > "3.5":
        print("Med student " + name + " made the honor roll.")

    if major == "Math":
```

Here is the **students6.py** file that is being imported:

```
def readStudents6(file):
    name = file.readline().rstrip()
    studentID = file.readline().rstrip()
    major = file.readline().rstrip()
    gpa = file.readline().rstrip()
    return name, studentID, major, gpa
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account.  [On topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and [... the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) apply here.
StackOverflow is not a design, coding, research, or tutorial resource.
However, if you follow whatever resources you find on line, make an honest coding attempt, and run into a problem, you'd have a good example to post.

Comment: You've already figured out how to read the file and extract information.  Computing an arithmetic mean is covered well on thousands of sites.  Please describe exactly where you're stuck with this?

Comment: Maybe start with a better data structure for representing the data.

Comment: After extracting the GPAs of math majors from the file (there are about 20 of them), I don't know how to calculate the average of those specific GPAs.

Comment: Unless you show how you are representing the data no one can help

Comment: I honestly don't really know how else to represent the data. I'm in an intro to python class and that's all we've been taught as of right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to represent the data, currently you are returning tuples from reading the file.
Store them in a list, create methods to filter your students on theire major and one that creates the avgGPA of a given student-list.

You might want to make the GPA a float on reading:

```
with open("s.txt","w") as f:
    f.write("OLIVER\n8117411\nEnglish\n2.09\nOLIVIA\n6478288\nLaw\n3.11\n" + \
            "HARRY\n5520946\nEnglish\n1.88\nAMELIA\n2440501\nFrench\n2.93\n")

def readStudents6(file):
    name = file.readline().rstrip()
    studentID = file.readline().rstrip()
    major = file.readline().rstrip()
    gpa = float(file.readline().rstrip())  # make float
    return name, studentID, major, gpa
```

Two new helper methods that work on the returned student-data-tuples:

```
def filterOnMajor(major,studs):
    """Filters the given list of students (studs) by its 3rd tuple-value. Students
    data is given as (name,ID,major,gpa) tuples inside the list."""
    return [s for s in studs if s[2] == major] # filter on certain major

def avgGpa(studs):
    """Returns the average GPA of all provided students. Students data
    is given as (name,ID,major,gpa) tuples inside the list."""
    return sum( s[3] for s in studs ) / len(studs) # calculate avgGpa
```

Main prog:

```
students = []

with open("s.txt","r") as f:
    while True:
        try: 
            stud = readStudents6(f)
            if stud[0] == "":
                break
            students.append( stud )
        except:
            break


print(students , "\n")

engl = filterOnMajor("English",students)

print(engl, "Agv: ", avgGpa(engl))
```

Output:

```
# all students    (reformatted)
[('OLIVER', '8117411', 'English', 2.09), 
 ('OLIVIA', '6478288', 'Law', 3.11), 
 ('HARRY', '5520946', 'English', 1.88), 
 ('AMELIA', '2440501', 'French', 2.93)] 

# english major with avgGPA    (reformatted)
[('OLIVER', '8117411', 'English', 2.09), 
 ('HARRY', '5520946', 'English', 1.88)] Agv:  1.9849999999999999
```

See: [PyTut: List comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) and [Built in functions](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html) (`float`, `sum`)

---

```
def prettyPrint(studs):
    for name,id,major,gpa in studs:
        print(f"Student {name} [{id}] with major {major} reached {gpa}")

prettyPrint(engl)
```

Output:

```
Student OLIVER [8117411] with major English reached 2.09
Student HARRY [5520946] with major English reached 1.88
```

Comment: I had completely forgotten how to filter based on tuple values. This is extremely helpful, thank you so much.

Comment: Is there a way to format the output of "math" so that it comes out in a column?

Comment: @marina what do you mean by "so that it comes out in a column"? you have your major-filtered list of students, simply print it. Or do `print( *[s[3] for s in engl], sep="," )` to get only the numbers ...